Providing register to nested input field using react-hook-form
I have built my own autocomplete field which references the query entered against an Array of towns/cities in the world.
This component has a container which holds the input field itself and the div that loads the autocomplete results based on the query.
I am using this field inside a form which is being handled using React-Hook-Form.
The issue: I am struggling to register this field, and so when the form is submitted, the data in the field is not submitted into the form, despite it displaying in the field.
I am using a FormProvider which wraps around the form. I am then getting the register method from the Form Context in the Autocomplete component, and then trying to register the input field. However, I get an error on load: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: register is not a function
The code:

The component:

function AutoCompleteInput() {
  const { register } = useFormContext();
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  function handleChange(e) {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleResultClick(result) {
    setValue(result);
  }

  return (
    <InputContainer>
      <StyledInput
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search for town/city..."
        {...register('departureLocation')}
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={value}
      />
      <ResultsContainer>
        {data
          .filter((item) => {
            const searchTerm = value.toLowerCase();
            const result = item.toLowerCase();

            return (
              value !== '' &&
              result.startsWith(searchTerm) &&
              result !== searchTerm
            );
          })
          .map((item) => (
            <Result onClick={() => handleResultClick(item)} key={item}>
              {item}
            </Result>
          ))}
      </ResultsContainer>
    </InputContainer>
  );
}

export default AutoCompleteInput;


The form (scaled down to just have the one field):

function CreateBookingForm() {
  const { createBooking } = useCreateBooking();

  const { handleSubmit, formState, methods } = useForm();
  const { errors } = formState;

  function formSubmission(data) {
    console.log(data);
    createBooking(data);
  }

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(formSubmission)}>
        {/* GENERAL INFO SECTION */}
        <FormSection>
          {/* LEFT COLUMN */}
          <FormColumn>
            <FormRow
              label="Departure location"
              error={errors?.departureLocation?.message}
            >
              <AutoCompleteInput id="departureLocation" />
            </FormRow>
          </FormColumn>
        </FormSection>

        <Button>Create booking</Button>
      </Form>
    </FormProvider>
  );
}

export default CreateBookingForm;

Any ideas why I am getting this error. I'm sure I'm not using this anywhere near right...
I've reviewed the docs and watched tutorials but can't see the solution.
Expecting that on submit of the form the value of the field is submitted.
